# GWT - How to view java exception stack trace in super dev?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm using GWT Super Dev and I activated source maps in Chrome. Although I can see the Java classes in the Sources tab, I can't figure out how to view the full stack trace of unhandled exceptions.

So how do I do that ?

Comment: Thanks for asking this common sense question as I would love to see a good description of how to accomplish this quite critical debugging operation that was so simple (though slow) before!  If not easy to do then it looks like it would be a very big step backward!

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue for it:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7460

However I've come to a workaround where I don't use the code server, but I integrate source map creation into a Maven-based project via a Maven profile. See this archetype for reference:

https://github.com/apetrelli/samplegwt